# GCC error when compiling MS VC++ code with templates

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

we're taking some code written for Visual Studio 2008 and try to compile it with gcc. We experienced an error in the following code (simplified to what's necessary):

```
template<int R, int C, typename T>
struct Vector
{
 template <typename TRes>
 TRes magnitude() const
 {
  return 0;
 }

};

struct A
{
 typedef Vector<3,1,int> NodeVector;
};

template<class T>
struct B
{
 void foo()
 {
  typename T::NodeVector x;
  x.magnitude<double>(); //< error here
 }
};

...
    B<A> test;
    test.foo();
```

GCC says

```
error: expected primary-expression before 'double'
error: expected `;' before 'double'
```

Can you explain the error to me? What's a cross-compiler solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Codepad link - does this work? - http://codepad.org/s5G0Cf6D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that since the C++ compiler doesn’t know the actual type of `T` (let alone `T::NodeVector` it doesn’t know that `magnitude` is supposed to be a template. You need to specify that explicitly:

```
x.template magnitude<double>();
```

Otherwise C++ will parse the tokens as `x`, `operator.`, `magnitude`, `operator<`, `double`, `operator>` …

The GCC is right, by the way. MSVC++ is notoriously lax on such matters.

Comment: Being lax isn't necessarily a bad thing if there's no ambiguities (as there aren't here).

Comment: @Blindy It is if it makes your code break on different compilers. Furthermore, you’re not entirely right, there *are* ambiguities here (assuming a conventional parser) due to template specialization, and that’s the reason why `typename` and `template` are needed here. Parsing this correctly is actually very, very difficult and can be very inefficient. The restriction may sound stupid but it actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Konrad, I don't think there's another way to parse the stream because the last `>` doesn't have an operand following it in function calls/member variables access/class name handles. Besides vendor specific extensions always break across compilers, think of `__declspec` and the like. They're still invaluable and irreplaceable.

Comment: @Blindy That’s why I said “assuming a conventional parser” – the parser cannot see what token comes behind the `double`, that would require arbitrary lookahead (well, 2 in this case but it could be much larger) and that is prohibitive in conventional parsers. The parser has to decide, at the point of seeing the `<`, whether to treat it as an operator or the beginning of a template list. MSVC++ does some *very* clever trickery to be able to parse this, but I’m wagering that there’s a trade-off somewhere.

Comment: @Blindy: "the last > doesn't have an operand following it" - in this case it doesn't, but it would if the function template had one or more arguments.

Comment: If you want an example that really is ambiguous without adding `template`, consider `template<int> void f(int);`, instantiated as `x.f < 3 > (4);`

Comment: @Mike, that still looks fine to me, there's no other way of parsing `id,<,listofstuff,>,open paranthesis`.

Comment: @Blindy: it can be parsed as either a call to a function template instance, `(x.f<3>)(4)`, or as an expression involving two comparison operators, `(x.f < 3) > (4)`. Without knowing whether `x.f` is a function template or a value, either is valid, so the expression is ambiguous.

Comment: @Mike, oh wow I totally missed that, you're right! I still think that it's not ambiguous to a compiler since it knows what `x.f` is at compiler time, but it is indeed more work for it.

Answer (score 1):

At the point of B it has no way to know what type x is, and that magnitude will be a template function so you need to declare it as one first.